# Can I use a Schottky Diode to prevent a voltage regulator from being used in reverse?

Tags: power-supply, diodes, voltage-regulator, 5v, 3.3v

When I use a USB Serial Programmer, the 3.3V line from the programmer gets connected to the 3.3V line from the circuit below.

The problem is that I also get 3.3v on the voltage regulator's VIn, supplying power to my other components hooked to the 5v net (not shown on the schematic). Could I use a Schottky diode in serial either in Vo->3V3 or 5v->Vin in order to prevent this? I think it might be better to use it on the input side of the voltage regulator since the voltage drop (0.3V) is less significant but then the voltage regulator will still be "on"

[image]

Comment: what would the diode on the input of U2 actually protect?

Comment: It would prevent powering my 5v line with 3.3v while I connect my USB programmer. I have a LED Matrix panel connected to my 5v line.

Comment: You could add a diode, but if this is a one time thing during initial programming and you don't expect another 3.3v supply to ever be connected, I would disconnect the 3.3v from the programmer and run off of USB power.

Comment: @rasco22862 but if you connect external 5V, then that diode doesn't do anything, because it's forward biased (5 V > 3.3 V). So, it solves no problem while there's external 5V.

Comment: @MarcusMüller exactly. I don't want the diode to do anything if there's external 5V connected. I only want to prevent this when I connect an external a 3.3 external power supply (the usb programmer)

Comment: but you don't connect that to the "+5V" net from your schematic, do you?

Comment: @user1850479 I see but the USB Programmer doesn't come with a 5v line that I could use

Comment: (I'm really just confused which *current* the diode is supposed to stop from flowing)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I guess it'd prevent the current from going to the other components I have connected to the 5v net (schematic is not showing them)

Comment: A Schottky on Vin side will protect from reverse current. Not sure if you should put it before the capacitors as well, but it sounds more logical to me.

Comment: You don't need to get the +5V from the USB programmer.  If you power the board normally when you program it and you can omit the diode and simplify your BOM (provided you never expect to hook a +3.3V source after you program it).

Comment: @user1850479 true but if I want to program a lot of boards then I'll have the burden of connecting both the 5v power supply and the usb programmer instead of the usb programmer only.